# On the antonym of "muito poucos"

Tags: gramática, antónimos

In the English language, there is both "very few" and "very many".  In the Portuguese language, however, to the best of my knowledge, there is "muito poucos" but "muito muitos" is nowhere to be found. If that is indeed the case, why? How can "muito" be used to amplify "poucos" but not "muitos"? Grammatically, do "poucos" and "muitos" belong to different "families"?

Comment: There is _muitíssimos_.

Comment: Indeed.  There is also "pouquíssimos".

Comment: The expression *muito muitos* seems grammatically correct, but it sounds horrendous to me.

Comment: @Schilive muito muitos não é correto.

Comment: @Schilive It sounds horrendous to me, as well, but that is no proof that it is grammatically incorrect

Comment: Very: (**used to add emphasis to an adjective or adverb) to a great degree or extremely**: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/very Very few people came to the party: Pouqu**íssima** gente veio a festa. íssima, issimo, issimas, issimos=VERY By the way, you can't prove a negative.

Comment: Esta pergunta se baseia na idea de que há equivalências entre as línguas. Só existe equivalência(s) de sentido(s) entre elas. Tradução literal não tem sentido em peguntas como essas.

Comment: Será que não seria hora de fechar essa pregunta? Já era.

Answer (score 0):

Question:
In the English language, there is both "very few" and "very many". In the Portuguese language, however, to the best of my knowledge, there is "muito poucos" but "muito muitos" is nowhere to be found. If that is indeed the case, why?

The translation of very few is: muito pouco, poucos, pouca, poucas
The translation of very many is: muitíssimo/a, os/as.

Ergo, Your comment is based on literal translation rather than on a translation of the actual meaning of the phrases.

VERY FEW
"Did a lot of people come to the party? Answer: **No, very few.**
"Muitas pessoas vieran a festa? Resposta: Não, **muito poucas**.
OU Pouquíssima gente veio a festa.

VERY MANY
There were not very many people at the party.
Havia poucas pessoas na festa.
Havia pouca gente na festa.
Não havia muitas pessoas na festa. [haver can also be ter.]

the **very** of **very few** is given in Portuguese by the ending on the adjectives": issima, issimo, issimas, issimos. The i is accented.

Comment: In my (Brazilian) experience, people think *muito pouco* sounds work when *pouco* is an adjective. For example, in "Muitas poucas pessoas".

Comment: @Schilive Já disse isso. muito poucas (veja acima), então pessoas é feminino, e ficaria "muito poucas pessoas", very few people. Eu falei isso: muito pouco, poucos, pouca, poucas. Obviamente, poderia se usar com o substantivo no singular, no plural, no feminino e no  masculino.